# Spring MessageBuilder vs Spring Integration MessageBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-messaging

Spring 4 introduced `org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder<T>`. And there is one existing `org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder<T>` in Spring Integration framework.

So when I am using Spring Integration with Spring 4, which message builder should I use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, both of them produce the same type of `Message` objects. So, no need to worry about the final result.

Anyway there is some tiny difference between them and for the Spring Websocket components it would be better to use `org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder<T>` and for Spring Integration components - another one.

From other side the best practice is to build your application based on the POJO and `MessageChannel` interaction. Having that you won't worry about builders at all, because you deal only with your domain.

Note: Spring Integration has built-in bean called `messageBuilderFactory`, which produces `MessageBuilder` by default. But you can override it to the `MutableMessageBuilderFactory` and all Spring Integration components (`IntegrationObjectSupport` extensions) will interact with `MutableMessageBuilder` and `MutableMessage` already.

Comment: But be very careful when using mutable messages - they are specialized and can have dangerous side-effects in a multi-threaded application. I don't recommend using them except in very specialized environments.